# Realtek RTL8723AE monitor mode

Tags: wireless, realtek

I have been trying for hours to set my wireless card into monitor mode. It's a Realtek RTL8723AE. The card works fine; I'm using it now to post this message. I just can't get it to monitor mode.

What I have tried so far:

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.
```

and then I tried setting it down before setting the mode

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
$ ifconfig
wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC  <MAC address removed>  
      inet addr:192.168.0.7  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1002 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:245662 (245.6 KB)  TX bytes:36399 (36.3 KB)
```

Here is some more output that may be useful:

* lspci ***

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0726]
```

### Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae

```
04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411     PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:0650]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

* iwconfig ***

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"greg_the_stop_sign"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
      Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=19/70  Signal level=-91 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10740   Missed beacon:0
```

* rfkill ***

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

I've tried everything I can think of :(

Comment: Did you try: sudo ifconfif wlan0 down; sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor; iwconfig wlan0? Does the mode stick?

Comment: Try using airmon-ng of the airecrack-ng suite, sorry if that's already been tried